# Read from property file in java vs read from Jenkins Env vars

Tags: java, properties, junit, jenkins, automated-tests

I'm running automated tests with WebDriver/Junit and the TestData is [injected to Jenikins env](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to be used in the tests. The problem with this is every time we need to run the test locally we need to comment the lines where the Jenkins env var are read and replace them with the correct values.

> //private final static String  DEFAULT_FILTER=System.getenv("DEFAULT_FILTER");
>   private final static String DEFAULT_FILTER="filter";

I think we can move to read the TestData from property file, I know the cost will be bigger, but I'm not sure about how expensive it can be. Is there a way to reduce the cost reading a property file? or it's better to continue injecting vars?

Comment: You can create a properties file, like XML with all possible values and access it in your code.

Comment: have different profiles in your build tools. One profile for Jenkins and one for local. Each profile references a different set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the conditional variables in the property file to distinguish either local or in Jenkins. As Peter said, you can also use different profiles with different sets of parameters.

Still, I think conditional variable would be better.

Comment: this sounds really good as I can have the pros from both worlds...but could you please provide more information about this approach? I searched here and google but I didn't found references to conditional variable. thanks in advance for your help